# How to do handle consecutive pushing/popping of View in a single function call

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

Question looks crazy, but I had faced an issue, in which I want to implement like this. Consider I have a view(A) showing currently, in one case I want to pop the view and show other view e.g.(ViewB) instead of ViewA, so What I have done is I have wrote a function in ViewA class to pop like this...

```
 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Next to the function call I am pushing new View, now app is crashing by saying.. Nested push may corrupt your navigation controller ......

What am I doing wrong here... Can't we do pop and push immediately...How to handle this case..

thanks.

Comment: Post some code which does above things..

Comment: If you want pop and push immediately just set the popViewControllerAnimated:NO

Comment: ... Or wait untill the animation ends...

Comment: @GuoLuchuan I have tried without animation but now it is crashing in viewwillappear method where I am setting label text.

Comment: @Newbee just have a try in the viewDidAppear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want pop and push immediately just set the popViewControllerAnimated:NO – Guo Luchuan

Answer (score 0):

You can try presenting your views modally and dismissing it. But if you want to do this with push and pop then you can do the following:
In your View A pop the view and set some flag which can be accessed in the previous view controller (i.e the view from where View A was pushed).
Next check this flag in the previous view's viewWillAppear and push View B.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Class base only popping A and pushing B. why do I need flag?

Comment: you don't want to push B every time viewWillAppear is called in the base class, right?